# Is there a way to specify "initial" values in css shorthands like padding?

Tags: css

Say I have a complex stylesheet with lots of interacting styles etc.

For a specific class, I want to override padding-top and padding-bottom, without changing the values of padding-left and padding-right (which might even be different things for different elements that get the class I'm specifying).

Is there a way to do this with a shorthand, something like

```
.special {
    padding: 10px initial 5px;
}
```

that leaves the previous values, or do I have to spell out my css like this:

```
.special {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't use something like 'initial', you should use `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

Comment: I suspected as much, but wanted to check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to specify it as in your second example, it's possible that the browser would interpret `inherit` in some means:

```
.special {padding: 10px inherit 5px inherit; }
```

but the inherited values would come from the parent element of `.special`, not necessarily the 'default' values.

---

**Edited** in response to comment:

> inherit can only be used as replacement for the value, not in place of a length (from "CSS: The Definitive Guide": values: [ | ]{1,4} | inherit.
>   @Lekensteyn

In consequence, then, it would be required to specify the values long-hand.

Comment: btw, lousy IE support, just saying.

Comment: This code won't work. `inherit` can only be used as replacement for the value, not in place of a length (from ["CSS: The Definitive Guide"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527334): `values: [<length> | <percentage>]{1,4} | inherit.`

Comment: @BoltClock's..: agreed. @Lekensteyn, that's what I thought (hence the "it's possible..."), but I wasn't sure about actual browser implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way around spelling it out. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know that the left and right padding will always be the same number, you could write it like:

```
.special {padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;}
```

Comment: Right, but I don't - hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not without using one of the css frameworks that have sprung up like Less: http://lesscss.org/