# Creating padding with one line of CSS without overriding defaults

Tags: css, sass

I have some CSS:

```
.header {
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

It would be much better organised as a single line, so instead we had:

```
.header {
   padding: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
 }
```

But this overrides the default values. I need a single line of code that doesn't override the default values.

Comment: `padding-top: 4px 4px 0px 0px;` isn't valid. It can only have a single value. Did you mean `padding: 4px 4px 0px 0px;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to specify "initial" values in css shorthands like padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670163/is-there-a-way-to-specify-initial-values-in-css-shorthands-like-padding)

Comment: @vishakh369 Please stop suggesting edits to questions by adding "Anyone?" at the end.

Comment: @j08691 I did mean `padding:`; very grateful to you for your help. Very funny about the "Anyone?" edits.

Comment: @Serlite Oh, it looks like it can't be done.

Comment: @WilmaFlintstone Yeah, unfortunately it looks like you'll have to go about it the more verbose way.

Comment: Can it be done with Sass or Less? I have edited the question and added the tags for these CSS preprocessors.

Comment: For Sass, no: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1339. Like they suggest in that thread, you'd have to use a mixin to get that sort of behaviour, since they try to match CSS syntax as closely as possible.

Comment: Are there any mixins which do this off the shelf or would I have to write a custom mixin?

Comment: @Serlite If Sass is capable of doing this with mixins, could you recommend a particular off the shelf mixins that could do it?